# how to create kafka listeners and add them dynamically in spring context

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, apache-kafka, dsl

hello i am developing a groovy dsl which allows to dynamically create kafka consumers with spring boot, exmple i can write.

```
consumer("topic1","group_id_1"){
//
}
consumer("topic2","group_id_2"){
//
}
```

and from this code I dynamically create two consumers kafka, consumer towards the topic "topic1" with a group id "group_id_1" and consumer towards the topic "topic 2" and with a group id "group_id_2" and add these two consumers in spring context application.